# Issue Trying to Pip Install facial_recognition library

Tags: python, pip, dlib, facial-identification

Running into the below errors involving the dlib

Googling,
installing Cmake on its own

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nmuytzc4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\
    Complete output (57 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.0b3 (v3.7.0b3:4e7efa9c6f, Mar 29 2018, 18:42:04) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Generator

```
    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/New Age/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-fs7bq7rc/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\NEWAGE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\NEWAGE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\new age\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\NEWAGE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\new age\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fs7bq7rc\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NEWAGE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nmuytzc4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

first you should install dlib for face recognition models. I used the Anaconda to install dlib in created environment,

**1. conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17**

use conda or pip to use install face recognition library.

**2. pip install face_recognition**

inside of the conda environment. for creating conda environment follow the instruction,

**conda create --name env_name python=version**

to activate env,
**conda activate env_name**

to deactivate env
**conda deactivate**